# Is there better alternative of XPath selector in Scrapy?

Tags: jquery, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Like title said, is there better alternative of XPath selector in Scrapy that can be used to easily select data in html? I found XPath has high learning curve and its syntax is somewhat difficult to use. I feel if jQuery selector can be used or incorporated in Scrapy, it could make life easier.

Comment: As I see it, this question is primarily opinion-based. "XPath has a high learning curve" or "its syntax is somewhat difficult to use" is not true for everyone. Likewise, jQuery selectors do not "make life easier" for everyone that uses Scrapy (for me, they would not).

Comment: are you asking this because pyquery (https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/) is used in pyspider (https://github.com/binux/pyspider) ? If that's the case what did you find easier ?

Comment: @euri10: lol, is that promotion? Thanks, I will look at pyquery. cheers.

Comment: @suud not promotion, I'm a simple user who begun using pyquery recently and found it quite similar as xpath, at least when used to scrape site. You may want to use Firepath in Firedebug, that helped me a lots learning how to construct xpath / sizzle / css !

Comment: @euri10: thanks for the firepath, but it will be better if there is tool to grab the xpath of attribute too. What is sizzle?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy [supports](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/):

> Scrapy comes with its own mechanism for extracting data. They’re
>   called selectors because they “select” certain parts of the HTML
>   document specified either by XPath or CSS expressions.

Example:

```
$ scrapy shell https://stackoverflow.com
>>> response.css('title::text').extract()
[u'Stack Overflow']
```

[FYI](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.css):

> In the background, CSS queries are translated into XPath queries using
>   [cssselect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssselect/) library and run .xpath() method.

Comment: Thanks, I know there is response.css(), but there is no selector by id, I have to use XPath with *[@id=""] thing to do it. Also the XPath uses one-based indexing for array, kinda confusing when just started to learn it. I feel XPath syntax is too verbose.

Comment: @suud it is either xpath or css, anyway

Comment: XPath is in fact no that complicated anyway. Not sure how you imagine a selection syntax that would be simpler, but xpath is worth learning, at least the basics.

Comment: @Lawrence: yes, it has learning curve. I'm getting on it right now. One of quirk of xpath is the array indexing start from 1, sometimes I forget that.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy selectors are built over `lxml` library, but you can use any mechanisms you prefer.

Other than the `XPath` selector, scrapy also supports the `CSS` selectors:

```
response.css('my_css_selector_expression')
```

You can find the CSS selectors reference here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Regular expressions are also supported:

```
response.selector.re('my_regex')
```

That said, I advise you to bite trough it and learn XPath, because it is very powerful and flexible, and supported by many extraction tools nowadays, it is de-facto standard.

Comment: Thanks, I know there is response.css(), but there is no selector by id, I have to use XPath with *[@id=""] thing to do it. Also the XPath uses one-based indexing for array, kinda confusing when just started to learn it. I feel XPath syntax is too verbose.